# optimal way to summarize data results

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have an app that executes some code A a number of iterations, usually up to 1M iterations.
After that code A has executed, I collect info such as time taken, error messages,if exception was thrown, etc in a specialized object lets say ExecutionInfo. I then add that instance of ExecutionInfo in a ConcurrentBag (nevermind the ConcurrentBag, it might as well be a List but needs to be threadsafe).

After 1M iterations I got a collection of 1M instances of ExecutionInfo. Next step is to summarize everything into lets say ExecutionInfoAggregation, using Linq extensions such as Average, Min,Max,Count for various interesting data. Following code runs after 1M iterations, and consumes 92% of hte CPU (says the profiler):

```
    private void Summarize(IEnumerable<MethodExecutionResult> methodExecutions)
    {
        List<MethodExecutionResult> items = methodExecutions.ToList();
        if (!items.Any())
        {
            return;
        }  
        AvgMethodExecutionTime = Math.Round(items.Average(x => x.ExecutionTime.TotalMilliseconds),3);
        MinMethodExecutionTime = Math.Round(items.Min(x => x.ExecutionTime.TotalMilliseconds),3);
        MaxMethodExecutionTime = Math.Round(items.Max(x => x.ExecutionTime.TotalMilliseconds),3);

        FailedExecutionsCount = items.Count(x => !x.Success);

    }
```

Btw, mem usage of app is 'skyrocketing'.

This is obviously not performant at all. My solution to this would be following:

Replace the collection type with a better suitable one, that allows fast insertions and fast queriying. What could that be, if any?
Dont query the collection after the 1M iterations, but aggregate after each code A execution. 
Try to find a more compact way to store collected data.

Any ideas how to optimize the queries? Is there a better approach?

EDIT: Just saw the call to ToList() is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Rather than saving info about each execution I would aggregate them after each method execution.

```
public class MethodExecutions
{
    private int _excCount = 0;
    private Int64 _totalExcTime = 0;
    private int _excMaxTimeTotalMilliseconds = 0;
    private int _excMinTimeTotalMilliseconds = int.MaxValue;
    private int _failCount = 0;

    public void Add(int excTime, bool isFail)
    {
        _excCount += 1;
        _totalExcTime += excTime;

        if (excTime > _excMaxTimeTotalMilliseconds)
            _excMaxTimeTotalMilliseconds = excTime;

        if (excTime < _excMinTimeTotalMilliseconds)
            _excMinTimeTotalMilliseconds = excTime;

        if (isFail)
            _failCount++;
    }

    public void Summarize(out int avgTime, out int minTime, out int maxTime, out int failCount)
    {
        avgTime = (int) Math.Round((double) _totalExcTime / _excCount);
        minTime = _excMinTimeTotalMilliseconds;
        maxTime = _excMaxTimeTotalMilliseconds;
        failCount = _failCount;
    }
}
```